# Upgrade WebLogic 10.3.0 to JSF 2 via webapp-provided JAR

Tags: jsf-2, upgrade, war, weblogic-10.x, java-ee-5

I have a Java EE 5 Web Application running on WebLogic 10.3.0.
I want to use JSF 2.x, but WebLogic 10.x only supports JSF 1.2.
So I did the following in order to use JSF 2.x instead.

1. I deployed a WAR cointaining those JARs:

   - wls.jsf.di.jar
   - glassfish.jstl_1.2.0.1.jar
   - javax.jsf_1.0.0.0_2-0.jar (jsf 2.0)
   - glassfish.jsf_1.0.0.0_2-0-4.jar
2. I added the following JARs to build path purely for compilation:

   - javax.faces-2.1.26.jar
   - jstl-1.2.jar
3. Created a Servlet 2.5 compatible `web.xml` and a `weblogic.xml` (1.0).
4. Included this in `weblogic.xml`:

   ```xml
   <library-ref>
       <library-name>jsf</library-name>
       <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
       <implementation-version>1.0.0.0_2-0-2</implementation-version>
       <exact-match>false</exact-match>
   </library-ref>

   <container-descriptor>
       <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
   </container-descriptor>
   ```
5. For EL 2.2-like method arguments support in EL 2.1, I added this JAR:

   - jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar
6. And placed this in `web.xml`:

   ```xml
   <context-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.faces.injectionProvider</param-name>
       <param-value>
           com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider
       </param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```

After all this changes WebLogic Console is still saying the following:

> Initializing Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_03-b04-FCS)
>   for context

As you can see, it is still using JSF 1.2. What else can i do to fully use JSF 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after doing some tests i was really using JSF 2! So yes, that is enough to make Weblogic 10.3.0 work with JSF 2. I don't remember if i got rid of the "Initializing JSF 1.2" message tho, i recommend to just ignore it

Comment: Did you get your configuration to log the correct version of JSF? I still get "Initializing Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_03-b04-FCS) for context" as my version in the log, despite a newer version clearly being in use when I print the result of `FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`.